# Jenkins Pipeline call Groovy script

Tags: xml, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to call the sample.groovy by passing test.xml as parameter to the goovy script from jenkins pipeline using below command

```
node('xxx'){
dir('E:\Project\workspace\dev'){
 bat 'call groovy Script\sample.groovy ".\Config\Managed File\Repo\test.xml" > output.log'

 }
 }
```

When i run the  call groovy Script\sample.groovy ".\Config\Managed File\Repo\test.xml" > output.log via Command prompt it works file. Below is the error message i am seeing when running through jenkins pipeline

```
E:\Project\workspace\dev>call groovy Script\sample.groovy ".\Config\Managed File\Repo\\test.xml"  1>output.log 
Caught: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
E:\Project\workspace\dev\call groovy Script\sample.groovy  
(E:\Project\workspace\dev\call groovy Script\sample.groovy)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
E:\Project\workspace\dev\call groovy Script\sample.groovy
(E:\Project\workspace\dev\call groovy Script\sample.groovy)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

Appreciate any pointers on this.

Comment: Did you try using a double backslash instead of a single backslash for the path? change: \ >> \\

Answer (score 0):

Try below script to confirm folder `Script` and `Config` and required files is under the workdir of `bat` via execute `dir`

```
node('xxx'){
   dir('E:\Project\workspace\dev'){
     bat 'dir'
     bat 'dir Script'
     bat 'dir Config\Managed File\Repo'
   }
 }
```